# SQL select statement with two AND's that contain multiple OR's

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having trouble understanding why the below code isn't working.

The second and third lines in the WHERE clause won't work together. If I take one out (either) they work. I am sure there is a term for what I am doing, but I cannot find it.

```
SELECT oh.location,SUM(od.net_ext) as retail_sales
FROM comm.dbo.ordhrd as oh
JOIN comm.dbo.ordetail as od
    ON od.location = oh.location
    AND od.invoice# = oh.invoice#
    AND od.inv_date = oh.inv_date
JOIN comm.dbo.invmas as inv
    ON inv.item_num = od.item#
WHERE type_of_rec = '01'
    AND ( inv.in_group = 'LABM' OR inv.in_group = 'LABQ' OR inv.in_group = 'LABP' )
    AND ( inv.category = 'LTAT' OR inv.category = 'LTMT' OR inv.category = 'LTHWY' OR inv.category = 'TOUR' OR inv.category = 'UHP' OR inv.category = 'SNOW' OR inv.category = 'STDLS' )
    AND od.inv_date BETWEEN '" . $current_start_date . "' AND '" . $current_end_date . "'
GROUP BY oh.location
```

Expected results would be results from filtered query

Comment: Are you sure that your data has records that match the criteria you are specifying? We can't tell without sample data.
Also, you can simply your query by replacing all the `OR` clauses with  something like `AND inv.in_group  IN ('LABM' , 'LABQ' , 'LABP' )`

Comment: `won't work together` mean wrong result or you have an error?

Comment: If I remove either line 2 or 3, the query will run with results. So yes, data exists for both. This is just the first time I have tried using double AND with multiple ( OR's ). `AND inv.in_group IN ( 'LABM' , 'LABQ' , 'LABP' )` and `AND inv.category IN ( 'LTAT' , 'LTMT' , 'LTHWY' , 'TOUR' , 'UHP' , 'SNOW' , 'STDLS' )`

Comment: Looks like it's working as intended. There are no rows that satisfy all three criteria

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza won't work was vague. Apologies. Will not return results. If I remove line 2 of the WHERE and leave line 3, it will return results.

Comment: You need to provide some sample data to allow others to test the query. Also you need to confirm that your date is being inserted in the correct format, because it appears you're adding the date as a string?

Comment: @Willee5586 If od.inv_date is not type datetime then convert it to a datetime value. This goes for $current_start_date and $current_end_date also.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add your in_group, category, and type_of_rec to your GROUP BY clause. If you still are not receiving results then there are several possible reasons your query is wrong. The join may not be limiting, the inv.category strings need `'% %'` wildcard characters, the format of BETWEEN clause may not be properly mapped (ie: wrong date format is throwing off results), etc.

Or, frankly, there might not be any records that meet your WHERE clause criteria. In the comments you state removing lines from the WHERE section fo your query makes it return rows. What does that tell you? Adding it back in may be too restrictive of a filter to return any rows.

Without posting sample data it is almost impossible for users on this site to judge what a valid query might look like.

I wrote something below that may be more flexible. It adds the columns referenced in your WHERE clause to the GROUP BY clause, formats your AND/OR clauses with IN clauses (improves readability/limits potential mistakes) and replaces the JOIN statements with LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT oh.location,
    SUM(od.net_ext) as retail_sales
    FROM comm.dbo.ordhrd as oh
    LEFT JOIN comm.dbo.ordetail as od
        ON od.location = oh.location
        AND od.invoice# = oh.invoice#
        AND od.inv_date = oh.inv_date
    LEFT JOIN comm.dbo.invmas as inv
        ON inv.item_num = od.item#
    WHERE type_of_rec = '01'
        AND inv.in_group IN ('LABM','LABQ','LABP' )
        AND inv.category IN ('LTAT', 'LTMT', 'LTHWY', 'TOUR','UHP', 'SNOW', 'STDLS')
        AND od.inv_date BETWEEN '" . $current_start_date . "' AND '" . $current_end_date . "'
GROUP BY oh.location, inv.in_group, inv.category
```